# Sftp download directory while excluding files with certain extension

Tags: linux, unix, sftp

So I know I can download a whole directory like this:

```
sftp> get -R *
```

How can I exclude all files with .ipa extension though? I want to download everything except .ipa or .ipa.* files from a directory.

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider usind `rsync` (if you have it available)? It supports an `--exclude` option, where you can specify what you wish to exclude:

```
rsync -av foo@remotehost:/dir/ /localdir/ --exclude .ipa --exclude .ipa.*
```

Comment: this is not a solution to the question. the question was, how to use sftp